# Does captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: carry any orientation information?

Tags: ios, orientation, avcapturesession, cmsamplebuffer

I apply tons of image processing to a camera live preview layer via OpenGL, and I want to get some information about the input`s orientation before I ask for the image from OpenGL (to apply corresponding transformations).

The capturing takes place in a portrait only viewController, and having notifications from the device orientation, or stuff may not be syncronized with the actual image orientation, I'm afraid.

Has CMSampleBuffer any orientation info? Or AVCaptureConnection?